# Google Chrome issue while inspecting website

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am working on web application, which is working fine.

Unless, I try to inspect HTML element. Sometimes, I am getting error.

> Aw Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage Error
> code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT

[image: Aw, Snap!]

Issue is not replicated everytime but somtimes only.

I am not sure what is causing such issue.

I looking for any guidance resolving the issue.

**Note: I get such issue only on chrome, not on other browser.**

Answer (score 0):

It may be a rendering issue. Try refreshing the page or sometimes it may be caused by extensions also. Try disabling extensions for the browser else change the browser. Also try to clear your browser cache.